# PHP dynamic session variable to query another page

Tags: php, session, elasticsearch, session-variables, html

I am new to PHP so I may be using the wrong method to accomplish this.  I am trying to use a session variable to store part of my query result: bugid 1, bugid 2, bugid 3 (query works great) and then use that result by clicking the bugid on page1.php to run a query using it on page2.php.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($results)){
        foreach($results as $r){        
        $_SESSION["bugid"] = $r ['_source']['BugID']; // assigning session value
        echo print_r($_SESSION["bugid"]);

    ?>
            <div class="result">
                <div><br><b>BugID: </b>
                <a href="page2.php"><?php echo $_SESSION["bugid"]; ?></a>
                </div>
                <div><b>AttachmentTitle: </b><?php echo $r ['_source']['AttachmentTitle']; ?></div>
                <div><b>AttachmentBody: </b><?php echo $r ['_source']['AttachmentBody']; ?></div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Below is the query on page2.php.  The problem is that it always uses bugid 3 regardless of which bugid I click on page1.php.  I am not sure if I got my question out clear enough, but I would appreciate any help you have even if its another solution!  Thanks.

```
$query1 = $Client->search([
    'index' => 'defects',
    'type' => 'detail',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                ['match' => ['BugID'           => $_SESSION["bugid"]]],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: why shouldn't it? you're setting $_SESSION in a loop, so only the LAST value set in the loop will still be in $_SESSION. You probably shouldn't be using a session for this anyways. what's wrong with using `<a href="page2.php?bugID=$bugid">...</a>`?

Comment: Well, I don't know much about PHP or HTML otherwise id have gone that route.  Thanks for the direction.  I figured it out!